# Replace a list on a service and see it changes in the view

Tags: angularjs

I have an angular app with a controller. I also have a service that holds a list of data - an array of objects with key-value. From time to time the list changes randomly. The service exposes the list to the controller. In my template I 'ng-repeat' the list. The thing is that when I update the list on the service, I don't know how to update the list in the view. The changing on the list occurs only on the data level but not on the UI level. **When I update an existing list I can see the changes in the ui, but when I replace the list with a different one, the view does not being update**.

[plunker demonstration](https://plnkr.co/edit/tNE9eg1JwQSy5kwdUNOS?p=preview)

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, getData) {
  $scope.values = getData.values
});

app.factory('getData', function($timeout){
  var values = [{key:"Good", value:"Morning"}];
  console.log(values)

  $timeout(function(){
    values.push({key:"Good", value:"Afternoon"})
    console.log(values)
  }, 500)

    $timeout(function(){
    values = [{key:"Good", value:"Night"}]
    console.log(values)
  }, 1000)

  return{
    values:values
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In second `$timeout` you are assigning a value to `values` variable by creating new reference of an object. That's the reason why the newly assigned array will not be seen on view.

Instead creating a new reference just clear out current array and extend the current object with new value. So that reference of object will get preserved and associate bindings will work as is.

**Code**

```
$timeout(function() {
    values.length = 0; //clearing array
    //extending current object with new values
    angular.extend(values, [{
      key: "Good",
      value: "Night"
    }])
    //instead of doing extend you can just push an objet as well.
    //values.push({ key: "Good", value: "Night" }]);
    console.log(values)
}, 1000);
```

[**Demo Plunkr**](https://plnkr.co/edit/fB2LXYnhdDbqA10SQPeA?p=preview)

Comment: suppose I pass the original reference of the list from the controller to the service and I replace the list. would angular then, in turn, "$watch" the changes ?

Answer (score 1):

This is caused when you create a new list and assign it to values. `$scope.values` is set to point to the service's `values` once, so when you update that same list (as you do in the first timeout using `push`) the controller sees that change. In the second timeout however you assign a completely new list to `values`, but the controller is still pointing to the original list.

Change the second timeout to the following to fix:

```
$timeout(function(){
    values.splice(0, values.length);
    values.push({key:"Good", value:"Night"})
    console.log(values)
}, 1000);
```